# To find nature of roots of $Ax^{4} + Bx^{3} + Cx^{2} + Dx - E $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

To find nature of roots of

$$f (x) = Ax^{4} + Bx^{3} + Cx^{2} + Dx - E $$

Where $A, B, C, D, E$ are all positive.

After applying [Descartes' Rule of signs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) to $f(x)$ there is one sign change , so there is $1$ positive root.

Doing same thing with $f(-x)$  there are $2$ sign changes, so there is either no negative root o two negative roots. But how do i say about other roots? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have established that there is one positive root from
$$f(x) = Ax^4+Bx^3+Cx^2+Dx-E$$
And that there are either three or one roots (not zero or two) from
$$f(-x) = Ax^4-Bx^3+Cx^2-Dx-E$$
So that means the possible combinations are 1 pos, 3 neg or 1 pos, 1 neg, 2 complex.

Comment: Observed by now: There is $1$ positive root and $3$ or $0$ negative roots. Now note that $f(0)=-E<0$ and $f(x)>0$ for $|x|$ very large. Hence there must be at least one negative root. Hence $f(x)=A(x-r_1)(x+r_2)(x+r_3)(x+r_4)$ with $r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4$ positive.

Comment: @ dardeshna I am sorry, my previous comment is not correct. Your answer is ok. There are two posibilities: (1) one positive zero and three negative, e.g., $f(x)=(x-1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+7)$, and (2) one positive, one negative and two complex zeros, e.g., $f(x)=(x-1)(x+2)(x^2+3)$.

Comment: No worries!  I got confused there for a second.  Using Descartes' Rule of signs yields the desired answer.